# preserve column-of-tibbles when using grouped summarise with reduce

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

#### Question

When using `tibble %>% group_by() %>% summarise(...=reduce(...))` on a column containing tibbles, I would like the output to remain a column of tibbles. How do I do that most efficiently?

#### Minimal Example:

**Setup**

```r
vec1 = rnorm(10)
vec2 = rnorm(10)
vec3 = rnorm(10)
vec4 = rnorm(10)

tib=tibble(grpvar=factor(c('a','a','b','b')))
tib$col2=1
tib$col2[1]=tibble(vec1)
tib$col2[2]=tibble(vec2)
tib$col2[3]=tibble(vec3)
tib$col2[4]=tibble(vec4)
```

*This is what it looks like:*

```r
  grpvar col2      
  <fct>  <list>    
1 a      <dbl [10]>
2 a      <dbl [10]>
3 b      <dbl [10]>
4 b      <dbl [10]>
```

A very minimal tibble with a variable that will be used for grouping, and another column containing tibbles which contain vectors of length 10.

**Problem**

Using `reduce` within `summarise` simplifies the output...

```r
tib %>% group_by(grpvar) %>% summarise(aggr=reduce(col2,`+`))
```

yields:

```r
   grpvar    aggr
   <fct>    <dbl>
 1 a      -0.0206
...
10 a      -0.101 
...  
20 b       0.520
```

Here, the tibble becomes very long ... I don't  want 10 rows per group variable, but instead just one tibble containing the 10 values.

**Desired output:**

This is what it should look like

```r
desired_outout<-tibble(grpvar=c('a','b'),aggr=NA)
desired_outout$aggr[1]=tibble(reduce(tib$col2[1:2],`+`))
desired_outout$aggr[2]=tibble(reduce(tib$col2[3:4],`+`))
```

***which looks like:***

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  grpvar aggr      
  <chr>  <list>    
1 a      <dbl [10]>
2 b      <dbl [10]
```

i.e., it retains the column-of-tibbles structure (which internally, I believe is a list of vectors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `reduce` with `list`:

```r
tib %>% group_by(grpvar) %>% summarise(aggr=list(reduce(col2,`+`)))
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  grpvar aggr      
  <fct>  <list>    
1 a      <dbl [10]>
2 b      <dbl [10]>
```

Comment: That works. I wonder how efficient it is and if `reduce` should offer a `simplify=FALSE` argument or so.